# How can i create an odometer/rolling meter life system like in the MOTHER series in Gamemaker Studio 1.4?

Tags: game-development, game-maker, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-1.4

I'd like to create an odometer life meter like in the MOTHER series, anyone knows what i can do?

I've already tried to search on google, i tried it to do myself but the only thing i got is a shitty meter which doesn't even display the right amount of health (this is for an Action-RPG btw.)

I would just like to recreate the odometer system in the mother games in to my project, could (please) somebody tell me how to do that/or give me tips about it?

Comment: can you give us additional information about what you want to create? you kept repeating "mother series" but not everyone knows it, I, for instance, don't know the series.

Comment: If you don't know what the  MOTHER series Is, then i guess you've never played JRPGS.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EarthBound_(series)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this in gms2:

create a control object if you still do not have it;

in create event

```
// @description event create
// variable lives or odometro

global.odometer = 5; // Example of player lives
```

in step event

```
// @description event step

// you create the condition to gain life
if (keyboard_check_pressed (vk_up)) // example of condition
{
    // create your actions by gaining life
    global.odometer ++;
}

// you create the condition to lose life
if (keyboard_check_pressed (vk_down)) // example of condition
{
    // create your actions by gaining life
    global.odometer -;
}
```

in draw event

```
// @description in draw event
// example of how you will show your odometro, create yours with your sprite or your odometro object

draw_set_color (c_red);
draw_text_transformed (x, y, string (global.odometer), 10,10, image_angle);

// Place the control object in the empty room and test it.
```